# Max potential difference that can be created in an analog signal using a microphone

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier, analog

I am a total newbie.

The main idea behind all this is that microphone produces analog signals which are fluctuation in Voltage.. So can I use an amplifier to amplify these Voltage? And after it can control the current flowing through circuit on the basis the input given to the microphone?

Comment: What property of sound do want to use to control the current? There is a really big black box between the microphone and the load without much specification as you've asked the question. Off the cuff you could use loudness (shout and it runs away), frequency (pitch), rhythm (remember The Clapper?), and more extending all the way to full speaker independent speech recognition ("stop", "go", "slower"). None of these cases have trivial answers.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what you are really asking.  Most microphones produce quite small signals relative to usual audio voltage levels inside audio equipment.  Audio "line" is about 1 V.  That level is easy to handle but large enough so that various subtle sources of noise are small enough relative to the signal to not cause much trouble.

Dynamic microphones directly convert sound power from the air into a electrical signal.  They usually put out a millivolt or less.  Piezo microphones are similar.  Electret microphones are common now, and when properly powered, usually produce up to a few millivolts.  Old telephone mouthpieces worked by having the sound pressure squish and squash graphite powder.  This varied the resistance across the powder, which could cause quite a significant signal.  You could apply a few volts directly to the series combination of such a carbon microcphone and a dynamic earpiece, and be able to hear quite well in the earpiece what the microphone picked up.

Since microphone signal levels are much smaller than what is required to drive a speaker or even line level, amplification is required.  This is what a *microphone preamp* does.  it amplifies the bare signal from a microphone and produces line level audio out, which can then be fed into other equipment.

Comment: What I want to do is to control the speed of motor using sound.

Comment: I haven't actually measured myself, though I do have the equipment for it, but I've read that a professional dynamic mic (the ever-popular Shure SM58 and its clones, for example) can produce 1V or maybe even 2Vrms if you scream directly into it.  Impedance is quite high though (kilo-ohms), so no running a motor from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the microphone data sheet, usually called "sensitivity". This parameter tells you how much electrical output signal a microphone will produce for a given level of acoustic sound.

Different microphone technologies have very different numbers, so I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run a motor from sound, you're not going to get very far with a direct connection.  Serious audio amps can handle massive amounts of power, mostly for real, but that's only because the speakers are perhaps 1% efficient or so.  99% of that power gets converted into heat in the speaker box.  In other words, loud sound really isn't all that powerful numerically.  You'll need a circuit that can listen to whatever mic you end up with and then run the motor using its own power.

If you're looking for something cheap and D.I.Y., then you might start here:

- Search YouTube for "sub kick mic".  The basic idea here is that a speaker can also act as a microphone, although less efficiently than a purpose-designed mic.  In fact, that's exactly how a dynamic mic works except that it's designed for the job.  I'm pretty sure you can get speakers more cheaply than mics.
- Search Google Images for "amplifier", "precision rectifier", "peak detector", "buffer amplifier", and "power amplifier".  That should give you enough building blocks that you can assemble something that works.  (not all may be needed)  The Images search should get you some fairly decent schematics, along with some other stuff that you'll have to weed out.  Post anything that's beyond you as separate questions here.  (questions plural; try to keep each one focused and on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an amplifier to build up the small electrical output from a microphone to do pretty much anything you want, including running a motor.

Presumably, you want the audio signal into the microphone to control the speed and direction of displacement of a motor's armature, and that's exactly what happens when an amplified audio signal is used to run a loudspeaker, which is nothing more than a linear - as opposed to a rotary - motor.

If you want to run a rotary motor, say a low-mass galvanometer or a d'Arsonval movement, that's also possible.

However, if you want to run a synchronous motor with an audio signal and have it respond quickly to changes in frequency and phase, then everything gets a little dodgy.